# Shipping method is missing on checkout - Magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, checkout, error, shipping-methods

We face a strange error in the checkout on the domain.com/checkout/#payment page, when clicking the place order button.

For some reason in some cases, we still can't find when exactly, the customer on checkout when clicking the place order button receive the error: `The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again.`

But we only have 1 active shipping method, the default "Flat Rate" method and is always select because it's the only value. And this issue can be solved by the customer, by moving back to the shipping step (domain.com/checkout/#shipping) and without any change directly go back to the payment step. Then clicking the place order button and it works perfectly.

We use a Cart Price Rule for free shipping, when the cart amount is above $50. Then the customer receive free shipping, otherwise the default Flate Rate is calculated.

Any idea what can cause this issue and how we can solve this?
We run Magento 2.4.4, but we had this issue also on 2.4.3

Comment: Check your logs what you get, then decide how to debug.

Comment: @Oscprofessionals Thanks, but the problem is that we do not see any error in the log, except this specific error that his message was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug this issue on the below class (It might be extended in any custom module):

```
\Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier
```

Check if this class extended. There is a method **collectRates(RateRequest $request)** used in this class which is responsible for shipping methods and rates.

Comment: Thanks, we only have 1 custom module, based on this that extended this: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/frontend/custom-checkout/add-shipping-carrier/ But our `public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)` always `return false;` And how is it possible that going 1 step back, it solves the issue after it?

Comment: Can you disable that module for testing and check if that issue still persist.

Comment: Yes, sure, we can. But because collectRates always return false, it should not make any difference right?

Answer (score 0):

This error NoSuchEntityException thrown in below file `Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement`
on saveAddressInformation method for getting shipping method rate by method code,whereas any issue on collectRates function occurred then shipping method because unavailable and cause the issue.

```
!$shippingAddress->getShippingRateByCode($shippingAddress->getShippingMethod()
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can we debug this. Well we use a Cart Price Rule for free shipping above $50, forgot to add it earlier to the question. How can we debug this?

Comment: Can you please add log as get_class_methods($method); before $result->append($method); and check the shipping price setting or not.